# While running the server in rails with ubuntu os am getting the following error in my local machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': File exists - /home/rank/rails/chethan/specslot/tmp/pids (Errno::EEXIST)
    from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in`fu_mkdir'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in`reverse_each'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in`each'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:71:in`block in start'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `each'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in`start'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in`tap'
    from /home/rank/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in`require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `'

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's another copy of `rails server` running.

Answer (score 0):

remove /home/rank/rails/chethan/specslot/tmp/pids and try to start server again. Looks like you had emergency shut down your machine recently